# Search by textbox and display in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, filter, listbox, userform

I'm trying to create a search that will display the information on the list box.

I'm trying to search by name and date range, or by name, or by date only.

I have code, the date is correct but it displays all the names.

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click() 

    Dim DateRange As Range, rCl As Range, rng As Range, Dn As Range 
    Dim Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date 
    Dim iX As Integer 
    Dim strName As String 

    Set DateRange = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(4) 
    Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(4) 
    Me.ListBox1.Clear 

    strName = Me.txtName.Text 
    Date1 = CDate(Me.txtDate.Value) 
    Date2 = CDate(Me.EndDate.Value) 

    For Each rCl In DateRange.Cells 
        For Each Dn In rng.Cells 
            If rCl.Value >= Date1 And rCl.Value <= Date2 And strName Then

            ElseIf Dn.Value = strName Then 

                With Me.ListBox1 
                    .AddItem Sheet2.Cells(rCl.Row, 1) 
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(rCl.Row, 2) 
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(rCl.Row, 3) 
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(rCl.Row, 4) 
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(rCl.Row, 5) 
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = Format(Sheet2.Cells(rCl.Row, 6), "hh:mm:ss") 
                End With 
            End If 
        Next Dn 
    Next rCl 
End Sub
```

Comment: You have your condition `If rCl.Value >= Date1 And rCl.Value <= Date2 And Dn.Value = strName Then ` and don't do the actions, and when the name match you add the itens, so you are adding everything .You should delete this line `ElseIf Dn.Value = strName Then `

Comment: Hi, I already tried deleting the statement ElseIf Dn.Value = strName Then - it still displaying everything and then for example I'm only filtering using the name I'm getting an error for the cdate because there is no value.

Comment: You are looping twice the same Range `For Each Dn In rng.Cells` and `For Each rCl In DateRange.Cells` Because DataRange and rng are the same. Although it won't solve the problem.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong. I should now erase the -For Each Dn In rng.Cells- and Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(4) -. am I right? Sorry. Im still new to VBA and trying to learn stuffs.

Comment: Could you please give and example of your data table? Because there are some things that are not right, like `Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(4)` Is column D, that you use to find dates and the stringname

Comment: Employee Name Department Position Date QA Score 
Here are my columns. So Ithink for the set rng the column should be 2 right? since the name is in column 1

Comment: +-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+----------------+

|       Employee Name      |  Dept  |          Position     | Date            |
+-------------------------------+---------+-----------------------+----------------+
| Virgilio Be                      | Opera | Level 1 Tec         |  15/09/2017 |
| Jo Arim                          | oper    | Level 1 tec          | 15/09/2017 |
+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------+---------------+

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are checking the date range only in the same line: Delete the second loop `For Each Dn in rng.Cells` as well as `Next Dn`) and replace the following condition with:

```
        If (rCl.Value >= Date1 And rCl.Value <= Date2) And rCl.Offset(0, -3).Value = strName Then
```

BTW, it's the better method to use arrays than range loops.

Comment: Hi, I will try this. Sorry for the late response.